# Multi Robot Mapping in Navigation_2d Tutorials

Tags: ros, slam, exploration, nav2d, multi-robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tutorials for the navigation_2d package are provided [here](http://wiki.ros.org/nav2d/Tutorials). The first 3 work flawlessly and, being a beginner, they have taught me a lot. However, the next 2 tutorials have very little documentation, namely the ones corresponding to the tutorial4.launch file in the package and a tutorial that helps one implement their own exploration strategy. They can be found at these links:
[tutorial4.launch](http://wiki.ros.org/nav2d/Tutorials/DistributedMapping)
[Exploration Strategy](http://wiki.ros.org/nav2d/Tutorials/Exploration)

I was wondering if anyone had managed to successfully implement tutorial4.launch file, the one which deals with multi-robot exploration and mapping. I would greatly appreciate it if you could give me a few pointers on how to set it up or maybe direct me to a link with a more detailed explanation of the working methodology.

Thank You!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192259/multi-robot-mapping-in-navigation_2d-tutorials/) by [Ashwin27](https://answers.ros.org/users/19896/ashwin27/) on ROS Answers with karma: 34 on 2014-09-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on 2015-05-21**:
Hello @Ashwin27, i have some problems to get nav2d exploration run on my turtlebot, may i ask what equipments did you use for your tasks with nav2d?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

these two tutorials do not exist, because I had no time to write them yet. :(
However, the tutorial4.launch should be in the package and should also run if you were able to run the first 3. So maybe the launch file can already answer some of your questions.

```
roslaunch nav2d_tutorials tutorial4.launch
```

If you are interested in writing your own exploration strategy, you should checkout the sources from Github and have a look at the NearestFrontierPlanner within nav2d_exploration. This is a very simple strategy to demonstrate how to write a plugin for the Navigator. Also the tutorials from http://wiki.ros.org/pluginlib can help you with this.

---

Originally posted by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) with karma: 1658 on 2014-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ashwin27](https://answers.ros.org/users/19896/ashwin27/) on 2014-09-09**:
Thanks for the quick response, Sebastian!
When I run the tutorial3 launch file, I have to enter these two commands to get the simulation to run:
rosservice call /StartMapping 3
rosservice call /StartExploration 2
What similar commands do I need to enter for tutorial4?

**Comment by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on 2014-09-09**:
I just had a look at the launch file and there is only the mapper running on all robots and the sim_joy node to control the simulated robots via joystick. So you can move the robots by holding down button 1 or 2 and moving the robot via the joystick.

**Comment by [Ashwin27](https://answers.ros.org/users/19896/ashwin27/) on 2014-09-10**:
I got it running now, thanks a lot for the help, Sebastian!